# Express.js with Vercel, throwing MIME Error

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, vercel

I am having trouble with launching my express.js app into Vercel.
I was told I needed to make a vercel.json file to include with my express webapp, here is what mine looks like:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "app.js",
        "use": "@now/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "handle": "filesystem"
      },
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "app.js"
      }
    ]
  }
```

this is what the link in my HTML looks like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/styles/socials.css">
```

I have also tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/socials.css">
```

and my file tree looks like this

```
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- public
|   |-- images
|   |   |-- //I have a lot of images in this folder
|   |-- scripts
|   |   `-- index.js
|   `-- styles
|       |-- header.css
|       |-- socials.css
|       `-- styles.css
|-- routes.js
|-- vercel.json
`-- views
    |-- _footer.ejs
    |-- _header.ejs
    `-- index.ejs
```

I have tried a couple configurations, and it seems like all of them threw the same MIME error
Is there something that I seem to be missing with Vercel? im using the default, or "other" configuration.